# Disable HTML/PHP output from rendering

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml

I have to retrieve xml in ajax, but I can't write a separate php script. The reason is because those data depend of the context: Libraries, constants, includes,etc... So the only way I found is calling url the normal way like `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/myApp?param=U` so the website loads the database abstraction layer, constants... but it also renders html. I want to clear all content before and after the xml part.

Here is a schema :

```
<html>
    ...constant loading, libraries...
    ...some html...
    ob_end_clean(); //It clears everything before and seems to work (?)
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    ...xml generation...
    ...some html ...
</html>
```

I've got xml syntax errors because of the html after xml generation.

To sum up, I need to send xml response and that's all.

What is the best way to achieve this ? Am I taking a really wrong way ? I am not a beginner in web but I am not an expert too.

Comment: Leave out the `<html>` and `</html>` tags, they're not needed if the script produces XML.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. This is not a script, this is a html page which produces xml in the middle.

Comment: The problem is that `ob_end_clean` removes all the earlier output from the buffer, so the `<html>` tag is removed. Therefore, `</html>` doesn't match anything. If you want the XML to be in the middle of HTML, don't clear the output buffer.

Comment: You should have a specific view for rendering xml, if you can change the script, maybe you could handle this with a special parameter like http://xx.xx.xx.xx/myApp?param=U&type=xml that would render only the xml part ?

Comment: Do I have to render xml ? I mean it is only to get some integer. I think I missundestand the way jquery/ajax retrieves xml data. Does it needs to be inside html tag or is there a specific protocol for xml ? Or maybe should I generate a distant xml file using fwrite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `exit;` after the XML so the HTML doesn't corrupt the XML document. You should be testing for whether PHP should render an HTML page or just the XML. Such as using the query string to specify you want XML output rather than HTML. Or, if you're going to be using the XML in JavaScript and you need Ajax to be working with XML, you could have PHP test for the presence of the X-Requested-With header like so:

```
<html>
    ...constant loading, libraries...
    ...some html...
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')
{
  $output='xml';
}
if($output=='xml')
{
  ob_end_clean();
  header('Content-type: text/xml');
}
?>
...xml generation...
<?php
if($output=='xml')
{
  exit;
}
?>
    ...some html ...
</html>
```

Comment: God... it was the keyword `exit`... Ok so the way i am doing now is `ob_end_clean();header('Content-type: text/xml'); ...xml generation... flush(); exit;`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the xml portion inside a `div`. and extract content from inside that div once you got the response.  [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/dssk1uuc/1/)

Comment: This solution works, but still is there any way to "disable" rendering at some point ?

Comment: means ? where do you want to disable rendering ?